# isset бесполезен?

Tags: php

Сколько пишу на `php` ни разу `isset` не пригодился. Я проверял даже - если в массиве нет ключа, но ты пытаешься его получить то возвращает `null` без ошибок (по мне так лучше бы исключение кидал как в других языках). В то же время `isset` вернет `false` и если ключ есть, но значение по этому ключу `null`, поэтому уж лучше тогда проверять `array_key_exists`. Так вот `isset` реально бесполезен?! Или есть какой-то толк?

P.S. Вопрос больше про применение `isset` с массивами. Ну наверное его можно применять для проверки существования переменной, хотя и то проще на null проверить с тем же успехом по моему. К тому же IDE обычно подсказывает если пытаешься использовать не инициализированную переменную.

Comment: Да, полностью бесполезен. В скорых патчах(PHP >12) должны пофиксить.

Answer (score 4):

Конечно есть, у вас скорее всего выключены Notice ошибки, и на самом деле у вас  очень в многих местах.

1. Как вы проверяете наличие $_GET, $_POST переменные на их наличие?
2. Небольшой пример который показывает что выводит ошибку при [echo $array[1];](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81561af6e1914ee3cc03cfb92d6220bf1f3b25c2)

Вообще проверять на наличие чего либо, стоит всегда. Вы конечно в чем то правы про null / false / array_key_exists. Но лучше всегда проверять. Ключом массива может переменная которой может быть. Или же может не быть входных параметров при запросе к базе данных, добавив isset вы только облегчите себе в дальнейшем читаемость и предсказуемость кода. Без банальных проверок, вы когда-нибудь при переезде на новый сервер можете быть сильно удивлены сколько все таки ошибок у вас.

Comment: Нотайсы тоже бесполезны (во всяком случае когда используешь фреймворк).

1. В Yii который я использую есть `ArrayHelper::getValue` для этого (да и в других фреймворках тоже есть подобные штуки). 
2. А вот тут ничего не выводит: https://glot.io/snippets/f0669ruru5

Comment: Автор как раз говорит, что с массивами можно использовать `array_key_exists`. С переменными Notice можно увидеть, например, здесь: `echo ($a == null);`, когда $a не определена

Comment: @DarkByte простите конечно, но я не использую ArrayHelper, тк я знаю что в "моих массивах". Если вы в программировании надолго, то лучше все таки придерживаться правилам хорошего тона. Почему спросите? Отвечу: так надо.

Comment: @lazyproger просто у меня такое ощущение что isset это пережиток прошлого и его уже можно депрекейтить.

Comment: Кроме того не забывайте что в 7.0 язык стал строже к проверкам, то что в 5.6 было notice стало error в 7.0

Comment: Так еще раз: для проверки наличия ключа в массиве правильнее юзать array_key_exists (о чем и свидетельствует название функции), а проверять существование переменной просто глупо если не говнокодить всякими extract и eval. IDE (во всяком случае phpstorm, а других нормальных php-ide и нету) и так отлично показывает места где переменная не проинициализирована. Таким образом для isset просто нет места и смысла.

Comment: @DarkByte в фреймворке Yii, который вы используете, ключевое слово `isset` встречается 1649 раз. Вы уверены, что прям так пережиток и можно деприкейтить?

Comment: @rjhdby ну скажем так для меня это лишь показывает низкое качество кода этого фреймворка :D (что впрочем не мешает мне пользоваться им)

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее частый кейс использования `isset` - проверка входных данных. Так как PHP, фактически, является языком обрабатывающим пользовательские запросы - этот кейс как никогда актуален.

@lazyproger совершенно верно акцентировал внимание на проверках `$_GET` и `$_POST`, от которых никуда не деться в любом проекте чуть сложнее landing page.

Касательно массивов - `isset` часто бывает полезен при валидации массивов, полученных посредством `json_decode` из json-ответа стороннего API например. В общем случае он будет работать быстрее, чем `array_key_exists` (на копейки правда, но все же), но с нюансом относительно NULL - это да. С другой стороны, полученный в ответ NULL зачастую, для логики приложения, равносилен отсутствию значения.

**UPD** немного кишок про isset и array_key_exists

```
$a=[];
isset($a['a']);
```

компилируется в

```
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return    operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  E >   EXT_STMT
         1        ASSIGN                                                   !0, <array>
   4     2        EXT_STMT
         3        ISSET_ISEMPTY_DIM_OBJ                       33554432  ~2      !0, 'a'
         4        FREE                                                     ~2
   6     5      > RETURN                                                   1
```

А это

```
$a=[];
array_key_exists('a', $a);
```

в

```
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  E >   EXT_STMT
         1        ASSIGN                                                   !0, <array>
   4     2        EXT_STMT
         3        INIT_FCALL                                               'array_key_exists'
         4        EXT_FCALL_BEGIN
         5        SEND_VAL                                                 'a'
         6        SEND_VAR                                                 !0
         7        DO_FCALL                                      0
         8        EXT_FCALL_END
   6     9      > RETURN                                                   1
```

Как мы видим, в первом случае на все про все один опкод `ISSET_ISEMPTY_DIM_OBJ`, во втором случае вызов подпрограммы с передачей туда сюда переменных и значений

Answer (score -1):

> *Вопрос больше про применение isset с массивами*

Используйте для работы с массивами соответствующие **[функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php)**.

**[isset()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php)** вам поможет определить, была ли установлена переменная значением, отличным от `NULL`. Эта конструкция так же бывает удобна для проверки нескольких переменных в одном выражении, например:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 1;
$c = null;
$d = 1;
$e = 1;

var_dump( isset($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) ); // boolean false
```